# How to run default dir command under FAR file manager?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, dir, far-manager

I have Cygwin installed somewhere in the path. So I have

```
>where dir
D:\Users\Dims\Design\Cygwin64\bin\dir.exe
```

When I run `DIR` from `CMD` I get the normal Windows `DIR`:

```
>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

...
```

But if I run it from under `FAR`, it takes `DIR` from Cygwin:

```
>dir /?
/usr/bin/dir: cannot access /?: No such file or directory
```

So, `FAR` is somehow ignoring precedence of built-in Windows commands. Is it possible to re-enable it?

Comment: What's your `path` env variable?

Comment: The `dir` you want to run is an internal command only available from Windows `cmd`

Answer (score 1):

[`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) is an [**internal command** of cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html), hence you **can't run it in any other shells** including Windows PowerShell. There's no separate `dir.exe`

```
C:\>where dir
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

There's no such thing like *"Windows dir"* or *"built-in Windows commands"*. In PowerShell `dir` and `ls` are aliases of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) so you'll get an output like this instead of cmd's `dir` command output

```
PS C:\> dir


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-r---        3/28/2017  10:13 AM                Program Files
d-r---        3/28/2017  10:13 AM                Program Files (x86)
d-r---         1/3/2017   3:04 PM                User
d-----         4/5/2017  11:14 AM                Windows
               4/5/2017   2:55 PM           8192 ntuser.dat
-a----         4/7/2017   9:45 AM            152 useragent.log
```

---

The closest (and only way) you could come is **calling `cmd` itself**

```
cmd /c dir
```

or `cmd /k dir` if you want the cmd shell to remain.

Answer (score 0):

In unix you can put a space before a command to ignore any alias of that command that is set up.  If such a thing exists in Windows command prompt, I don't know what it is.  I think that's what you're really asking.

The closest fix I can find is to use the `&` command separator.  For example, `ECHO & DIR` will run the normal `DIR` command, but it will print `ECHO is ON.` first.  I can't think of any DOS command that has no output.

But if you're running into this problem, you probably have a `test.exe` command in the cygwin/msys/git bash bin directory, which has no output, so you can get around it with `test & dir`.

Or, of course, you could make an empty batch file to put on the left side of the `&` separator.

**Edit:** Actually, I was playing around and `DIR & ;` works and doesn't require any external command.

**Edit 2:** The command in parentheses `(DIR)` works.  Maybe that's the shortest thing.